# Prove that exists only one scalar product $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has $u, v,w$ as orthonormal basis

Tags: orthonormal, bilinear-form

Let  $ u = (1, −1, 0), v = (0, 1, 1), w = (1, 1, 0) $ be vectors of $\mathbb{R}^
3$.

Prove that exists only one scalar product $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ in  $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has $u, v,w$ as
orthonormal basis.

Any idea to begin with?

I've think about the idea that the matrix $M(\langle \ , \ \rangle, \mathscr{S} ) = I_3 $, with $\mathscr{S}$ a Sylvester basis. Because of the fact that an euclidian geometry is an orthogonal geometry with Sylvester invvariant $r_0=0, r_+=n, r_-=0$. But I'm not sure at all...

Any help? Thanks!!

Comment: proof of existence and uniqueness is immediate. On the other hand, the matrix (half the Hessian matrix) of a quadratic form changes basis by $P^T MP.$ For your question, some care is needed as to the elements in $P$

Comment: orthonormality isn't even needed in this problem.  If a vector space has two inner products which agree on a basis, they have to be equal.  The value of the inner product on the basis completely determines the inner product. See my proof below.

Comment: OK I see your idea! Then there can't be two equal inner products and that proves the uniqueness of the product. I've seen your proof, that's a good one! And well, there has to be an orthonormal basis because all orthogonal geometry admits an orthogonal basis. Too useful! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Right. Another way to look at it is like this. An inner product on  a vector space is equivalent to a choice of orthonormal basis.  Once you declare a basis to be orthonormal, you have uniquely determined an inner product on the vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can be more general than that.  Let $V$ be a vector space and let $u_1,\dots, u_n$ be any basis on $V$.  Let $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle_0$ and $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ be two inner products on $V$ such that
$$
\langle u_i,u_j\rangle_0 = \langle u_i,u_j\rangle_1
$$
for all $i,j$.  We want to show that
$$
\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_0=\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_1
$$
Let $v,w\in V$.  Then we can express it as a linear combination of $u_1,\dots, u_n$:
$$
v=\sum_i v^i u_i,\hspace{0.2in} w=\sum_i w^iu_i
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\langle v,w\rangle_0&=\sum_{i,j}v^iw^j\langle u_i,u_j\rangle_0\\
&=\sum_{i,j}v^iw^j\langle u_i,u_j\rangle_1\\
&=\sum_{i,j}\langle v^iu_i,w^ju_j\rangle_1\\
&=\langle v,w\rangle_1,
\end{align}
$$
which proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle'$ inner product for which $u,v,w$ is an orthonormal basis. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ $$ x= \langle x, u\rangle' u + \langle x, v \rangle' v + \langle x, w \rangle' w .$$ Taking the inner product of this with respect to the original inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ gives $\langle x ,u \rangle = \langle x ,u \rangle'$, $\langle x ,v \rangle = \langle x ,v \rangle'$ and $\langle x ,w \rangle = \langle x ,w \rangle'$. This implies $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle = \langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle'$.

A note: there was nothing special here about the fact we were working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or the specific values of $u,v,w$.